# Floatrow package is affected in figure environment

Tags: floatrow

I am using floatrow package creating the box environment. if i declare the floatrow package in the tex file the normal figure framebox is affected.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatother
\DeclareNewFloatType{Box}{%
  placement=htbp,%
  name=BOX,%
}%

\floatsetup[Box]{%
  style=BOXED,%
  capposition=top,%
  justification=justified}%



\newenvironment{BOX}[2][htbp]{%
\begin{Box}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box}}%

\newenvironment{BOX*}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box*}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box*}}

\newcommand{\processfigure}[2]{\centering\fbox{\parbox{82mm}{\rightskip12pt\centering#1\vspace*{-3.5pt}\par\rightskip12pt%
\caption{#2}}}}%

\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{BOX}[!t]{The polymers were dissolved in dimethylsulfoxide (DMSO)}
The polymers were dissolved in dimethylsulfoxide (DMSO) at  The ratio polymer/DMSO was about 1:10 (mg/mL). After evaporation to around 1/3 of the original volume, the solution was spread on a glass plate, using a doctor-blade type equipment, and then put in the oven for the casting treatment at 120 for 24\,h. After the casting, membranes were stored at ambient humidity and peeled off (called in the following ``first treatment'').
\end{BOX}

\lipsum[6-10]


\begin{figure*}[!t]
\processfigure{Figure Placed here\vspace*{12pt}}
{\textbf{\boldmath Cross-link reaction for SPEEK (color code: gray C, yellow S, red O)}.\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[11-15]

\end{document}
```

Before declare the floatrow package the figure environment output displayed below:

[image]

After declare the floatrow package the figure environment output displayed below:

[image]

Defined box environment using flotrow package displayed below

[image]

I don't know what is the reason to affect the figure environment if i am using floatrow package. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using the `floatrow` package, which permits you to have boxed `figure`s simply declaring

```
\floatsetup[figure]{style=BOXED,captionskip=25pt}
```

I've added a `captionskip` since you want some spacing before the caption.

Then, instead of using

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\processfigure{Figure Placed here\vspace*{12pt}}
{\textbf{\boldmath Cross-link reaction for SPEEK (color code: gray C, yellow S, red O)}.\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}
```

with your custom command `\processfigure` to construct a box around the `figure`, simply use a `\ffigbox` in this way:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\ffigbox[82mm]
{Figure Placed here}
{\caption{\textbf{\boldmath Cross-link reaction for SPEEK (color code: gray C, yellow S, red O)}}\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewFloatType{Box}{%
  placement=htbp,%
  name=BOX,%
}%

\floatsetup[Box]{%
  style=BOXED,%
  capposition=top,%
  justification=justified}%



\newenvironment{BOX}[2][htbp]{%
\begin{Box}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box}}%

\newenvironment{BOX*}[2][htbp]{%
  \begin{Box*}[#1]%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\caption{\textbf{#2}\vspace*{-6.5pt}}\fi%
}{\end{Box*}}


\floatsetup[figure]{style=BOXED,captionskip=25pt}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{BOX}[!t]{The polymers were dissolved in dimethylsulfoxide (DMSO)}
The polymers were dissolved in dimethylsulfoxide (DMSO) at  The ratio polymer/DMSO was about 1:10 (mg/mL). After evaporation to around 1/3 of the original volume, the solution was spread on a glass plate, using a doctor-blade type equipment, and then put in the oven for the casting treatment at 120 for 24\,h. After the casting, membranes were stored at ambient humidity and peeled off (called in the following ``first treatment'').
\end{BOX}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\ffigbox[82mm]
{Figure Placed here}
{\caption{\textbf{\boldmath Cross-link reaction for SPEEK (color code: gray C, yellow S, red O)}}\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[11-15]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i got the solution